# Use HomeLink button in car to toggle light controlled by smart switch

Tags: bridge

A few months ago, I bought a 2023 Honda Civic with built-in trio of HomeLink buttons.

I don't have a garage, but I *do* have a front porch light I'd love to be able to toggle on and off from inside the car on the driveway using one of those buttons (or, if push came to shove, use one button to turn it on, and one button to turn it off).

I *think* that what I'm trying to find is either:

- An electronic switch with a transmitter that pretends to be a garage door opener transmitter & whose only purpose is to train the HomeLink transmitter in the car, and toggles the state of the light it's controlling whenever it receives a button-press transmission from the car (or someone inside the house presses the button on the switch itself).
- Something that pairs to the HomeLink transmitter in the car as if it were a garage door opener... then, whenever it receives a button-press transmission, relays the on-off-toggle request to something like a generic wifi smart switch via something like wifi, zigbee, etc.

**Can anyone identify one or more real products that actually DO something like this?**

Note: just to be perfectly clear, the system in my car is **not** Bluetooth-based "HomeLink Connect"... it's HomeLink, period. No apps or anything involving Android/IOS or the infotainment center are involved. There are literally three buttons on the rearview mirror that expect to be trained by something that looks (to them) like a garage door opener transmitter.

Comment: created homelink tag ... it should show up when edit is approved

Comment: what kind of garage door opener remote controls can be copied to the vehicle? ... most door openers these days use encrypted codes

Comment: I'm not sure. As far as I can tell, HomeLink is kind of like X10... a really, really old standard that peaked years ago, but still shows up in new stuff because a) lots of people have older garage door openers, and b) for people who live in gated communities, even weaker security is probably more than good enough.

Comment: That said, it almost sounds like present-day openers NOW implement security "on the wire" and force you to use a proprietary, expensive button-module INSIDE the garage as well, as opposed to a doorbell button and a pair of wires that could easily be closed by a relay controlled by a non-vendor-blessed thirdparty receiver module.